# On click event not fired

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, button

I'm having trouble with the onclick event of a button from `Bootstrap`. The button is inside a table, but the `onclick` event is not fired. I'm tryin the attribute `onclick='<code>'` and `JQuery`: `$(".follow-button").on('click', function(){<code>})`. Here is the button

```
<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm follow-button" id="follow8">Follow</button></td>
```

It is inside a table with class `table table-hover` from `bootstrap 3`. Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.table').on('click', '.follow-button', function() {<code>});
```

Comment: Gimme a sec while I get you a good resource on why - I could explain it but even typing this comment I'm already past two lines lol

Comment: @user6827 Your code is not working because, When the time of registering that event, Dom doesn't have any elements with that signature. So you should use event-delegation to over come that issue.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/ not too far down the page will explain `delegation` pretty well actually.  It really has to do with the time that the element is brought into the page vs. when the javascript is executed

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled the class name,

Try this,

```
$(".follow-button").on('click', function(){<code>}).
```

Instead of

```
$(".button-follow").on('click', function(){<code>}).
```

---

If you are creating those buttons at the runtime then try to use event-delegation([.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)) like this,

```
$('body').on('click', '.follow-button', function() {<code>});
```